# Keystore for Android app

Tags: android, eclipse, keystore, android-keystore

I exported application for the first time and I'm a little bit confused about keystore.

I want to use one keystore for all next apps. So in Eclipse I will make new keystore but what to put in Alias? Can I put there app name or what? Because I want make universal keystore for all kinds of apps. Can I will put different Alias in my next app? Or will be better to put in alias my first and last name?

Is keystore visible when someone decompile your app?

Thanks for little explanation about keystores.

Comment: Use your first and last name -- your virtual signature (provided by the keystore) verifies the author of an app, and should not provide information about the app itself.

Comment: And no one can't see this informations (alias, name, last name) if they decompile my app, right?

Comment: I'm not sure if they could see it specifically by decompiling your app. I'm not sure you're thinking about this the right way. The purpose of signing your app is to create accountability. It's so that something public: your name; can be inseparably attached to something private: your code; via something secure: your PGP key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keystore is simply a file format designed to contain one or more keys, a.k.a. certificates.  It doesn't matter whether you keep all your keys in a one keyfile, and it doesn't matter what you name the keyfiles or the key aliases.  Nothing but the actual content of the key itself has any affect whatsoever on your app.

The keystore does not normally become part of the app, and you should make sure not to put it in your `/res` folder or anywhere else where it might end up getting compiled into the APK.  In fact, it's probably a good idea to keep it outside the project directory entirely.  Most of the strength of the key is in the practical impossibility of guessing or regenerating its contents.  If someone acquires a copy of your keystore, the only thing stopping them from publishing bogus versions of your app is whatever password you put on it.

If you want to split hairs, the docs are wrong.  The certificate does not identify the author of the app.  It only proves that the app was signed by someone who was in possession of your key.  Protect your keystores!

Comment: What a great explanation Kevin! Thank you! I will use default Eclipse wizard for signing application.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have one keystore file for all the apps then you cannot change the alias name. It is asked during creating the keystore file.
Next time whenever you compile and build the apk file you have to use the existing keystore file.

Hope you understood.